# Is there an expression language to query from flatbuffers (using JAVA)?

Tags: el, flatbuffers

I have a generated flatbuffers object in Java. I need to query for a field at runtime based on user input. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to dynamically query fields in Java, you have to know the field's name statically to retrieve its value. So best you can do is `if (user_input == "field") return obj.field()`.

There is a way to find out what fields are in a schema dynamically, by inspecting a binary schema file (which can be generated with `flatc --schema myschema.fbs`). Sadly, there is no reflection helper code in Java yet that will allow you to use that information to read an actual field (C++ only so far).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if any work is being done on reflection helper code?

My use case is that I need to filter out objects which match a pattern. I'm thinking about using groovy to filter. If user input is "field IS some_val", I can call "field()==some_val" groovy filter. Thoughts?

Comment: @wittyameta I don't know that anyone is working on reflection for Java. Also not familiar with groovy :)